Solidworks API table
I'm having a problem with generating a table with VBA. I'm getting an error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method to the following line: value = swTable.SetCellText(rowindex + 1, 1, prefix). I know that the form is wrong, but I couldn't understand how it should go from the web https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/swdocmgrapi/SolidWorks.Interop.swdocumentmgr~SolidWorks.Interop.swdocumentmgr.ISwDMTable~SetCellText.html. If a clever guru could help a newbie, I would be extremely grateful.
What I'm trying to accomplish that the number of rows always adds up depending how many notes there are on a drawing, the number of column is always 2, and that the first column (for eg if all notes have the form of PMAxx-xxx, x is the number) is PMAxx and the second column is xxx, depending if there are multiple of the same PMAxx, then the numbers after - add up. My whole code is the following:
 Dim swApp As Object
 Dim resultDict As Object
 Dim prefix As Variant
 Dim number As Double
 Dim rowindex As Integer
 Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
 Dim swView As SldWorks.View
 Dim swNote As SldWorks.Note
 Dim annotations As Object
 Dim noteText As String
 Dim parts As Variant
 Const MATABLE As String = "C:\Users\xx\Documents\PMA.sldtbt"
 Dim swTable As SldWorks.TableAnnotation
 Dim swDrawing As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
 Dim value As Integer
      
    
    
Sub GenerateSummaryTable()
  
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swDrawing = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swView = swDrawing.GetFirstView

    Set resultDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If swDrawing Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No drawing open."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set swNote = swView.GetFirstNote
    Do While Not swNote Is Nothing
        ' Check if the note text contains "PMA"
        noteText = swNote.GetText
        If InStr(noteText, "PMA") > 0 Then
            ' Extract the prefix and number (e.g., PMA17-100)
            parts = Split(noteText, "-")
            If UBound(parts) > 0 Then
                prefix = Trim(parts(0)) ' e.g., "PMA17"
                number = Val(Trim(parts(1))) ' e.g., 100

                If resultDict.Exists(prefix) Then
                    resultDict(prefix) = resultDict(prefix) + number
                Else
                    resultDict.Add prefix, number
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Set swNote = swNote.GetNext
    Loop

    rowindex = 1
    Set swDrawing = swModel
    
    Set swTable = swDrawing.InsertTableAnnotation2(False, 10, 10, swBOMConfigurationAnchor_TopLeft, MATABLE, resultDict.Count + 1, 2)

    If swTable Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Table object is not initialized"
     Exit Sub
    End If

    If resultDict Is Nothing Or resultDict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The resultDict is empty or not initialized"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    For Each prefix In resultDict.Keys
        value = swTable.SetCellText(rowindex + 1, 1, prefix)
        value = swTable.SetCellText(rowindex + 1, 2, CStr(resultDict(prefix)))
        rowindex = rowindex + 1
    Next prefix

    MsgBox "Table generated successfully."
End Sub



Do you get this error on all lines/cells of the table? I guess SetCellText doesn't return a integer (see example in the documentation you linked)

I only get it at the "value = swTable.SetCellText(rowindex + 1, 1, prefix)" part

You you get this error when rowindex is 1? Have you changed the type of value?

I think you're mixing up the document manager API with the solidworks API. The ITableAnnotation uses .Text2(row, col, includeHidden) to set cell contents.   https://help.solidworks.com/2018/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ITableAnnotation~Text2.html
